# How to use "RequiredScope" attribute functionality without using heavy "Microsoft.Identity.Web" NuGet package?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, .net-8.0

I am implementing authorization with custom scopes in my .NET8 API, and I came across the `RequiredScopeAttribute` while reading the [Protected web API: Verify scopes and app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore) article.

Here's the code snippet that looks perfectly fine, and is exactly what I was looking for.

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Web

[Authorize]
public class TodoListController : Controller
{
    const string scopeRequiredByApi = "access_as_user";

    [HttpGet]
    [RequiredScope(scopeRequiredByApi)]  <--- This attribute
    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> Get()
    {
        // Do the work and return the result.
        // ...
    }
 // ...
}
```

### Problem

I'm not using Azure AD (Microsoft Identity Platform); instead, my solution might use Amazon Cognito, Okta, Auth0, or another IdP. The `RequiredScope` attribute is packaged into `Microsoft.Identity.Web` NuGet package.

First of all, this `Microsoft.Identity.Web` NuGet package is itself very heavy, as it has dependencies on 57 other NuGet packages. See below screenshot.

My concerns:

- I can secure my API with only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` NuGet. But, if I need the `RequiredScope` functionality, why do I need to install such a huge NuGet package, which also includes an array of Azure dependencies that I am not even using?
- Why did Microsoft or the .NET team make it so Azure-centric?

I just want to achieve `RequiredScope` functionality with other IdPs using a small general purpose NuGet package, not with the one which is designed specifically for Microsoft Identity Platform.

[image]

Comment: Can’t you write your own attribute which works like “RequiredScopes” attribute? Just look at the code of this attribute and write your own?

Comment: That I can, and I will. But before that I was just checking if I am missing something or a better way is available.